# How can i know the minor on Linux module initialisation

Tags: linux-kernel

I am writing a linux kernel module.

Here is what i've done in module's init function:

```
register_chrdev(300 /* major */, "mydev", &fops);
```

It works fine. But i need to know the minor number.

I have read we cannot set this minor number. It is the kernel which gives us this number. If so, how can i know it in module's init function ?

Thanks

Comment: You simple can not. `->init()` runs once at module load. Afterwards other callbacks are in use.

Comment: So how can i know the minor number attached to my module ? It is not displayed in lsmod

Comment: Start your question from the point why do you need to know it in the first place?

Comment: I need to know the minor number which is affected to my module

Comment: **Why** do you need it? You still didn't answer. So, perhaps someone else can help you.

Comment: My goal is just to understand the kernel. I am creating a module in order to execute kernel code. I have a userland program which opens device in /dev so this program needs to know both major and minor in order to create /dev file with mknode

Comment: This is available thru *sysfs*. In the same way `udev` does it. Look at its source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`register_chrdev` calls `__register_chrdev` internally.

```
static inline int register_chrdev(unsigned int major, const char *name,
                  const struct file_operations *fops)
{
    return __register_chrdev(major, 0, 256, name, fops);
}
```

If you will see `__register_chrdev` function signature, it is

```
int __register_chrdev(unsigned int major, unsigned int baseminor,
              unsigned int count, const char *name,
              const struct file_operations *fops)
```

`register_chrdev` will pass your major number`(300)` and a base minor number `0` with a count of `256`. So, it will reserve 0-255 minor number range for your device.

Also, in the definition of  `__register_chrdev`, `dev_t` structure is created (contains major & minor number) for your device.

```
err = cdev_add(cdev, MKDEV(cd->major, baseminor), count);
```

`MKDEV(cd->major, baseminor)` creates it. So, the first device number(`dev_t`) will have `0` as its minor number. Besides, `count(256)` is the consecutive minor numbers that can be further used.

You can also dynamically get the major & minor number if you use `alloc_chrdev_region`. All you have to do is pass a `dev_t` struct 
to `alloc_chrdev_region`. It will dynamically allocate a major and minor number to your device. To get the major and minor number in your module, you can use

```
major = MAJOR(dev);
minor = MINOR(dev);
```

Comment: Slight correction required: reserved minor number range will be 0-255.